# Update dataframe column based on another dataframe column without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

df1:

```
id val
1  25
2  40
3  78
```

df2:

```
id val
2  8
1  5
```

Now I want to do something like `df1['val'] = df1['val']/df2['val']` for matching `id`. I can do that by iterating over all `df2` rows as `df2` is a subset of `df1` so it may be missing some values, which I want to keep unchanged. This is what I have right now:

```
for row in df2.iterrows():
    df1.loc[df1['id']==row[1]['id'], 'val'] /= row[1]['val']
```

df1:

```
id val
1  5
2  5
3  78
```

How can I achieve the same without using for loop to improve speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df1['val'] = df1['val'].div(df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['val']), fill_value=1)
print (df1)
   id   val
0   1   5.0
1   2   5.0
2   3  78.0
```

Solution with `merge` with left join:

```
df1['val'] = df1['val'].div(df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')['val_y'], fill_value=1)
          
print (df1)
   id   val
0   1   5.0
1   2   5.0
2   3  78.0
```